# How do I add a custom Ca to the truststore in newman?

Tags: postman, newman

I am using Newman to run some tests. The URL I am testing against uses certs signed by my org CA and theefore I get an ssl error. Is there a way to add the org CA to newman's trust store? I know I could use --insecure but I would much rather not.

Comment: Anything in here that could help?https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#ssl-client-certificates

Comment: Thank you but I dont think so. It looks like most of that is to provide a client cert to the server. In this case the client (newman) is not trusting the server cert and I want to  add a certificate authority as a trusted CA

Comment: You could raise an issue / question on the Newman repo in GitHub. It will reach the team and be able to give you an answer or potential solution.

Comment: @VibhaGopal did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for posterity - use the environment var NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to point to your trust store